# Convert from ISO-8859-2 to ORACLE char set AL16UTF16

Tags: php, oracle, encoding

Hello this is a follow up questing from yesterday,

I have a php script that is parsing a website. I am getting strings in UTF-8 now i want to insert those strings into my Oracle database which uses:

```
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET = EE8ISO8859P2
```

I have tried with :

```
$rep = iconv("UTF-8","AL-16UTF-16",$string);
```

// FAILS - produces ?? in database or scripts fails with "wrong charset"

I have also tried with

```
$rep = iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-2",$string);
$rep1 = iconv("UTF-8","AL-16UTF-16",$rep);
```

same as above ... fails with ?? in database.

Anyone has any idea what should i try next?

Comment: I think EE8ISO8859P2 is the Characterset you need to convert to, ignore AL16UTF16.

Comment: Yes but problem is if i type it like this: $rep1 = iconv("iso-8859-2","EE-8ISO8859P2",$rep); it fails with error: Wrong charset, conversion from `iso-8859-2' to `EE8ISO8859P2'

Comment: I am not really a expert on PHP, but when I look at your second code-snippet, you change it from `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-2` and than try to change that string to `AL-16UTF-16`. I'd try to delete the second step.

Comment: Same problem ... Notice: iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `UTF-8' to `EE8ISO8859P2' is not allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OCI driver implicitly handles charset conversion. When connecting, ensure you set your charset as `UTF-8`:

```
oci_connect($username, $password, $connection_string, 'UTF-8');
```

This tells OCI to expect you to provide strings in UTF8 format and to provide resultsets in UTF8, converted from the database charset. From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) (emphasis mine):

> Determines the character set used by the Oracle Client libraries. **The character set does not need to match the character set used by the database. If it doesn't match, Oracle will do its best to convert data to and from the database character set.** Depending on the character sets this may not give usable results. Conversion also adds some time overhead.

This means, assuming that the strings you want to input are in UTF8, that you shouldn't need to use `iconv()` at all.  Just let OCI handle that for you.

Comment: ^ THIS GUY! Much apreciated!  Instead of UTF-8  as char set you have to supply your Database character encoding but i have never had idea that you can even do that with a parameter in oci_connect funtion.

Comment: Thanks, for me : oci_pconnect($username, $password, $connection_string, 'UTF8')